# Remove duplicate items in ArrayList using for loop only

Tags: java, arraylist

You are given the following sequence of numbers,
1, 652 ,5, 15, 385, 4 , 55, 666, 13, 2, 4658, 9, 55, -588, 10, 1083, 17 ,4.
You can remove the duplicate numbers by only using For loop and ArrayList.

```
public class Ex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(652);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(15);
        list.add(385);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(55);
        list.add(666);
        list.add(13);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(4658);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(55);
        list.add(-588);
        list.add(10);
        list.add(1083);
        list.add(17);
        list.add(4);


        System.out.println("Before remove : " + list);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if (list.get(i) == list.get(j)) {
                    list.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After remove duplicate items : "+list);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Before remove : [1, 652, 5, 15, 385, 4, 55, 666, 13, 2, 4658, 9, 55, -588, 10, 1083, 17, 4]
After remove duplicate items : [1, 5, 385, 55, 13, 4658, -588, 1083, 4]
```

Some items that not duplicated is missing. Ex 10 and 652.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: @NicholasK post updated.

Comment: what if i == j ?

Comment: After removing `j`, the next `get` is going to get `j+2`

Comment: use list.sort and then iterate (once) again.If you have dublicates (and not triplecates) , you'll be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many issues:

1. You will remove non-duplicate records when `i == j`. To avoid that the inner loop should start with `int j = i + 1`.
2. When you remove records, you should decrement `j`, since all the elements following the removed element are shifted one index down.
3. You should compare `Integer`s with `equals`, not with `==`

Comment: 4. the raw type

Comment: @AndrewTobilko good point, but that doesn't affect the correctness of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop always starts with `j = 1` which means you will remove every single element of the list except the one at index 0. You should instead let `j = i + 1`. The inner loop will then only check the following elements of the list and not the one you are comparing. After removing you should use `j--` so the index of the next element corresponds to j. And you can use `==` when comparing primitive types (`int`) When comparing reference types (`Integer`) you should use `equals`.

This is what i suggest:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(i) == list.get(j)) {
                list.remove(j);
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about other values: 15 or 666? Are you sure you expect correct output?
It is much better to use `Iterator` to remove elements from the list:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    ListIterator<Integer> it = numbers.listIterator();
    numbers.removeIf(num -> isDuplicated(numbers, it.previousIndex(), num));
    return numbers;
}

private static boolean isDuplicated(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int toPos, int val) {
    for (int pos = 0; pos < toPos; pos++)
        if (numbers.get(pos) == val)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Output:

```
Before remove : [1, 652, 5, 15, 385, 4, 55, 666, 13, 2, 4658, 9, 55, -588, 10, 1083, 17, 4]
After remove duplicate items : [1, 652, 5, 15, 385, 4, 55, 666, 13, 2, 4658, 9, 55, -588, 10, 1083, 17, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArrayListExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ArrayList with duplicate elements
        ArrayList<Integer> numbersList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8));
        System.out.println(numbersList);
        Log.d("DBG",numbersList+"");
        // ArrayList without duplicate elements
        LinkedHashSet<Integer> hashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(numbersList); 
        ArrayList<Integer> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(hashSet);
        System.out.println(listWithoutDuplicates);
        Log.d("DBG",listWithoutDuplicates+"");
    }
}
```

input

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8]
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Code for Duplicates not allowed ... for upper example
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if(list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))){
                    list.remove(j);
                    j--;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

ublic class RemoveDublicate
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(652);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(15);
    list.add(385);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(55);
    list.add(666);
    list.add(13);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(4658);
    list.add(9);
    list.add(55);
    list.add(-588);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(1083);
    list.add(17);
    list.add(4);
        System.out.println(list);
        
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++)
            {
                
                if(list.get(i)==list.get(j))
                {
                    list.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);


}
```

}